# Method when called virtually calling itself recursively

Tags: c#, clr

I've been reading CLR via C# and I read the following:

Sometimes, the compiler will use a call instruction to call a virtual method instead of using a callvirt instruction. At first, this may seem surprising, but the code below demonstrates why it is sometimes required:

```
internal class SomeClass {
// ToString is a virtual method defined in the base class: Object.
public override String ToString() {
// Compiler uses the ‘call’ IL instruction to call
// Object’s ToString method nonvirtually.
// If the compiler were to use ‘callvirt’ instead of ‘call’, this
// method would call itself recursively until the stack overflowed.
return base.ToString();
}
}
```

When calling base.ToString (a virtual method), the C# compiler emits a call instruction to ensure that the ToString method in the base type is called nonvirtually. This is required because if ToString were called virtually, the call would execute recursively until the thread’s stack overflowed, which obviously is not desired.

Although it is explained here I don't understand why ToString called virtually would execute recursively. Could someone provide another explanation or desribe it in a more simple fashion if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `base.ToString()` you actually want to call base class implementation of ToString() method.

If you simply call `this.ToString()` method will be invoked "virtually", i.e. the `ToString()` of actual class would be called.

In your example, if `base.ToString()` would be called "virtually", it would be the same than `this.ToString()` this would end in `ToString()` method invoking again the same `ToString()`and therefore would be an infinite recursion ending in a stack overflow.

Comment: He can also try out `public override string ToString() { object thisAsObject = this; return thisAsObject.ToString(); }` inside a class.

Comment: In release build (with optimizations on) it usually will not end in stack overflow (it doesn't in .NET 4.6 64-bit). The JIT compiler can optimize the call as a tail call, so it will not create a new frame on the stack. With optimizations off, it will be a stack overflow.